# C++ : Bus Error: 10 when assign string passed in method

Tags: c++11, bus-error

I am trying to assign a `string`  whose value is passed into the method when I got this error :

`Bus error: 10`

My code:

```
struct user {
   string username;
   string password;
};
```

The method:

```
user *init_user(const string & username, const string & password){ 
    user *u = (user *)malloc(sizeof(user));
    if (u == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    u->username = username;
    u->password = password;
    return u;
 }
```

Calling:

`user *root = init_user("root", "root");`

I think the error is raised by

```
u->username = username;
u->password = password;
```

The compiler I'm using is `c++11`

OS: `MacOS`

Comment: Don't use `malloc()` to allocate a type that has any members (such as `std::string`) with non-trivial constructor/destructor.   The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. The problem has been solved

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` does not call constructors, so that the strings you assign to are invalid, hence `SIGBUS`.

In C++ use `new`, it allocates memory and calls the constructor for you:

```
user *init_user(const string & username, const string & password) { 
    user* u = new user;
    u->username = username;
    u->password = password;
    return u;
}
```

---

The factory functions should return a smart-pointer, like `std::unique_ptr` to convey the transfer of ownership and prevent memory leaks:

```
std::unique_ptr<user> init_user(const string & username, const string & password) { 
    std::unique_ptr<user> u(new user);
    u->username = username;
    u->password = password;
    return u;
}
```